# How can I keep BibLaTeX from abbreviating the "von part" of an author's name in authoryear style?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I'm writing a document in `authoryear` style. Two of my references happen to have the same last name, and hence their first names appear on the citations. That's expected, but I see also that `biblatex` is abbreviating the "de" particle (common in Portuguese, and corresponding to the "von part" found in some other European languages), a feature I do not desire. I tried using `prefix-i={de}` to solve it, but it kept abbreviating to "d." (with a dot). I also tried working around by using `shortauthor`, but this approach didn't seem useful either.

How can I keep `biblatex` from making this abbreviation?

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,
  title = {Stochastic Approach to Equilibrium and Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics},
  author = {Tomé, Tânia and family=Oliveira, given=Mário José, prefix=de, useprefix=false},
  date = {2015-04-29},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {91},
  number = {4},
  eprint = {1503.04342},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.91.042140},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {042140},
  langid = {english}
}

@article{oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous,
  title = {Finite-Size Scaling for Discontinuous Nonequilibrium Phase Transitions},
  author = {family=Oliveira, given=Marcelo M., prefix=de, useprefix=false and family=Luz, given=M. G. E., prefix=da, useprefix=false and Fiore, Carlos E.},
  date = {2018-06-08},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {97},
  number = {6},
  eprint = {1804.00467},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.97.060101},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {060101},
  langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Obtained: \cite{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous}.

Desired: Tomé and M. J. de Oliveira 2015; M. M. de Oliveira, Luz, and Fiore 2018.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### MEW with `prefix-i={de}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,
  title = {Stochastic Approach to Equilibrium and Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics},
  author = {Tomé, Tânia and family=Oliveira, given=Mário José, prefix=de, prefix-i={de}, useprefix=false},
  date = {2015-04-29},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {91},
  number = {4},
  eprint = {1503.04342},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.91.042140},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {042140},
  langid = {english},
}

@article{oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous,
  title = {Finite-Size Scaling for Discontinuous Nonequilibrium Phase Transitions},
  author = {family=Oliveira, given=Marcelo M., prefix=de, prefix-i={de}, useprefix=false and family=Luz, given=M. G. E., prefix=da, useprefix=false and Fiore, Carlos E.},
  date = {2018-06-08},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {97},
  number = {6},
  eprint = {1804.00467},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.97.060101},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {060101},
  langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Obtained with \verb|prefix-i={de}|: \cite{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous}.

Desired: Tomé and M. J. de Oliveira 2015; M. M. de Oliveira, Luz, and Fiore 2018.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Result with `prefix-i={de}`

[image]

#### MWE with `shortauthor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,
  title = {Stochastic Approach to Equilibrium and Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics},
  author = {Tomé, Tânia and family=Oliveira, given=Mário José, prefix=de, useprefix=false},
  date = {2015-04-29},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {91},
  number = {4},
  eprint = {1503.04342},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.91.042140},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {042140},
  langid = {english}, 
  shortauthor = {Tomé, Tânia and family=Oliveira, given=Mário José, prefix=de, useprefix=true},
}

@article{oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous,
  title = {Finite-Size Scaling for Discontinuous Nonequilibrium Phase Transitions},
  author = {family=Oliveira, given=Marcelo M., prefix=de, useprefix=false and family=Luz, given=M. G. E., prefix=da, useprefix=false and Fiore, Carlos E.},
  date = {2018-06-08},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {97},
  number = {6},
  eprint = {1804.00467},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.97.060101},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {060101},
  langid = {english},
  shortauthor = {family=Oliveira, given=Marcelo M., prefix=de, useprefix=true and family=Luz, given=M. G. E., prefix=da, useprefix=true and Fiore, Carlos E.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Obtained with \verb|shortauthor|: \cite{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous}.

Desired: Tomé and M. J. de Oliveira 2015; M. M. de Oliveira, Luz, and Fiore 2018.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### Result with `shortauthor`:

[image]

#### Remarks:

While I'm trying to roughly follow Chicago guidelines, I'd rather not use `biblatex-chicago` because I'm using `biblatex-ext` functionalities elsewhere that seemed troublesome with that package. Hence, I'd prefer a solution closer to `authoryear`. Notice I do want to keep `useprefix=false` in the bibliography. Ideally, the solution would be easily implemented in Zotero as well, but I understand that might be way more difficult to do (if possible), so I'll also accept answers that ignore Zotero completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formatting of the name in citations is controlled by the `labelname` name format. It branches according to the different `uniquename` values.

Its default definition is

```
% Used in some citations
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

So that `biblatex` uses the abbreviated name prefix `\namepartprefixi` when only initials are needed and `useprefix` is `false`. We always want to use `\nameprefix` instead, so can get rid of the `\ifuseprefix` test for good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffixi}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,
  title = {Stochastic Approach to Equilibrium and Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics},
  author = {Tomé, Tânia and family=Oliveira, given=Mário José, prefix=de, useprefix=false},
  date = {2015-04-29},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {91},
  number = {4},
  eprint = {1503.04342},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.91.042140},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {042140},
  langid = {english}
}
@article{oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous,
  title = {Finite-Size Scaling for Discontinuous Nonequilibrium Phase Transitions},
  author = {family=Oliveira, given=Marcelo M., prefix=de, useprefix=false
            and family=Luz, given=M. G. E., prefix=da, useprefix=false and Fiore, Carlos E.},
  date = {2018-06-08},
  journaltitle = {Physical Review E},
  shortjournal = {Phys. Rev. E},
  volume = {97},
  number = {6},
  eprint = {1804.00467},
  eprinttype = {arxiv},
  primaryclass = {cond-mat.stat-mech},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevE.97.060101},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eid = {060101},
  langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Obtained: \cite{tome2015StochasticApproachEquilibrium,
  oliveira2018FinitesizeScalingDiscontinuous}.

Desired: Tomé and M. J. de Oliveira 2015; M. M. de Oliveira, Luz, and Fiore 2018.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Obtained: Tomé and M. J. de Oliveira 2015; M. M. de Oliveira, Luz, and Fiore 2018.]